# Night light not working in Ubuntu 20.04.2. What can I do now?

Tags: 20.04, night-light

Night light is not working in my computer since last boot. Battery was less than 40% when I booted. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Is Night Light turned on in your Settings/Displays/Night Light panel?

Comment: Yeah it's turned on always. Actually I keep it turned on for a scheduled time and set the time so that it covers around 22 hours making it sure that remaining two hours fall in the duration I sleep. Btw now after the battery got charged it's working and don't know why.

Comment: @heynnema I guess that's a bug. I faced the issue once the battery was nearly full. How can I report it?

Comment: Turn OFF, then turn ON, the Night Light setting. Also reset the Power Manager by shutting down the computer, then hold down the POWER button for ~30 seconds. That should probably take care of it. You can't report a problem that can't be reproduced with the developers computers.